# Property 'display' must be of type 'FontDisplay', but here has type 'string'

Tags: javascript, typescript, datatables

After completing a course at Udemy I am trying to convert my Javascript project (a browser game) to TypeScript.

My package.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@tweenjs/tween.js": "^21.0.0",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.16",
    "@types/tweenjs": "^1.0.4",
    "pixi.js-legacy": "^7.2.4"
    "datatables.net-dt": "^1.13.4",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  }
}
```

My tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "rootDir": "./src/main/typescript/",
    "outDir": "./src/main/resources/js/",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

As first I have tried converting a file holding random functions, among others the callbacks for datatables.net -

My incomplete Utils.ts:

```
declare global {
    let UID: number;
    const COUNTRY: string;
    const SHOW_LINKS: boolean;
    const SHOW_PHOTOS: boolean;
}

export function renderOpenElo(data, typeStr, row, meta) {
    return typeStr === 'display' ? '<SPAN CLASS="xlarge">&rtri;</SPAN> ' + chessPiece(data) : data;
}

export function renderPhotoGiven2(data, typeStr, row) {
    var photo = SHOW_PHOTOS ? (row.photo || row.photo2 || PHOTO_HAPPY) : PHOTO_HAPPY;
    var given2 = SHOW_LINKS ? '<A TARGET="_blank" HREF="/___LANGUAGE___/player-' + row.player2 + '">' + escapeHtml(data) + '</A>' : escapeHtml(data);
    return '<IMG CLASS="avatar" SRC="' + photo + '" ONERROR="brokenImage(this);"><P>' + given2 + '</P>';
}
```

Unfortunately, when I run `npx tsc src/main/typescript/Utils.ts` I now get the errors:

```
node_modules/@types/css-font-loading-module/index.d.ts:22:9 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'display' must be of type 'FontDisplay', but here has type 'string'.

22         display?: string | undefined;
           ~~~~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:549:5
    549     display?: FontDisplay;
            ~~~~~~~
    'display' was also declared here.

node_modules/@types/css-font-loading-module/index.d.ts:42:9 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'display' must be of type 'FontDisplay', but here has type 'string'.

42         display: string;
           ~~~~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:8482:5
    8482     display: FontDisplay;
             ~~~~~~~
    'display' was also declared here.

node_modules/@types/css-font-loading-module/index.d.ts:47:35 - error TS2583: Cannot find name 'Set'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the 'lib' compiler option to 'es2015' or later.

47     interface FontFaceSet extends Set<FontFace>, EventTarget {
                                     ~~~


Found 3 errors in the same file, starting at: node_modules/@types/css-font-loading-module/index.d.ts:22
```

This confuses me, because I do not even use any fonts in my Javascript game.

The `typeStr` argument is passed to my callbacks by datatables.net and sometimes has the "display" string as value.

Is this error even related to something I am doing in my newbie TypeScript code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the issues by executing once:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/node
npm install --save-dev @types/css-font-loading-module
```

Now my package.json looks like the following:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@pixi/ui": "^0.7.3",
    "@tweenjs/tween.js": "^21.0.0",
    "datatables.net-dt": "^1.13.4",
    "pixi.js-legacy": "^7.2.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/css-font-loading-module": "^0.0.8",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.16",
    "@types/node": "^20.3.1",
    "@types/tweenjs": "^1.0.4",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  }
}
```